# por que no funciona click con li?

Tags: php, vue.js

Estoy imprimiendo una lista a medida que el usuario ingresa los datos en el `input` para mostrarle las coincidencias, pero al hacer click en la lista este no le asigna el valor al `input`, les juro que esto antes funcionaba, ahora no se por que dejo de funcionar, aquí les dejo el código:

`js`:

```
hola: function(i) {
    this.new_name = i;
    this.showlist = false;
}
```

vista:

```
<div id="product_ul">
    <ul v-if = "showlist  == true">
        <li v-for="i in filteredProducts" @click="hola(i)">
            {{i}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

`this.new_name` es el nombre del `input` en donde se escribe.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la función de esta manera

```
hola (i) {
    this.new_name = i
    this.show_list = false
}
```

Comment: no funciona, de verdad no se porque pasa esto, en otro archivo lo probe y funciona

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a crear un método como cualquier otro:

```
function hola(i) {
    this.new_name = i;
    this.showlist = false;
}
```

Si aún así sigue sin funcionar, prueba a añadir el `onclick` de javascript:

```html
<div id="product_ul">
    <ul v-if = "showlist  == true">
        <li v-for="i in filteredProducts" onclick="hola(i)">
            {{i}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

En principio con esto no deberías tener problemas, otra cosa es que se adapte bien a tu código. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: ya vi porque no funcionaba, era porque el input estaba con el evento onblur a la vez, y al parecer onblur se ejecuta antes que click algo raro de js

Comment: Sería interesante que publicaras una respuesta (y la marques como correcta) de como solucionaste ese problema por si otra persona de la comunidad le pasa lo mismo. Un saludo